# Is there any to get discord token using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, discord, puppeteer

I am trying to get the discord token from puppeteer.

I have tried running the `page.evaluate()` but it just returns an error.

Code:

```js
const token = page.evaluate(
    (webpackChunkdiscord_app.push([
      [""],
      {},
      (e) => {
        m = [];
        for (let c in e.c) m.push(e.c[c]);
      },
    ]),
    m)
      .find((m) => m?.exports?.default?.getToken !== void 0)
      .exports.default.getToken()
  );
```

Error:

```
(webpackChunkdiscord_app.push([
     ^

ReferenceError: webpackChunkdiscord_app is not defined
```

Comment: Where are you getting `webpackChunkdiscord_app` from?

Answer (score 1):

## get the token

```js
const localStorage = await page.evaluate(() =>  Object.assign({}, window.localStorage));
const token = localStorage.token;
```

### other way

```js
const originalAgent = await browser.userAgent();
let data = { email: email, password: password, undelete: false };
let headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json', 'user-agent': originalAgent };
axios.post('https://discord.com/api/v8/auth/login', data, { headers: headers })
  .then(response => {
    let token = response.data.token;
    console.log(token);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.captcha_key) {
      console.log('\u001b[32m>\u001b[37m Discord Returned Captcha, Try Again Later');
    } else if (error.response && error.response.data && error.response.data.password) {
      console.log('\u001b[32m>\u001b[37m Invalid Password');
    } else {
      console.log('\u001b[32m>\u001b[37m An Error Has Occured');
    }
  });
```

#### login with token

```js
await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(token => {
  localStorage.clear();
  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}, 'your-token-here');
```

Comment: Against all expectations, this code actually works! I can't thank you enough. We've been searching for the solution all week!